# JavaScript / jQuery  why doesn't this work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function checkSession(){
    $.ajax({url: "session.php", success: function(data){
         if( data == 1){
             var postFilen = 'msg.php';
             $.post(postFilen, function(data){
                 $("#msg").html(data).find("#message2").fadeIn("slow")
            }
         } else {
             $('#message2').hide();
         }
    }});
// setInterval('checkSession()',1000);
}
```

Basically, this is checking if data is 1 in session.php, and if it is, it should run msg.php´s div #message2 in #msg

Comment: What is not working? Any errors?

Comment: You are missing `);` for `$.post(`. Is this code correct?

Comment: I dont get any errors.. How "format" my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you formatted your code more logically it would be clearer what your intentions were with this.

In your $.post() call, you close the curly brace on the function, but you don't close the $.post() paren.

Replace:

```
$.post(postFilen, function(data){
    $("#msg").html(data).find("#message2").fadeIn("slow")
}
```

with:

```
$.post(postFilen, function(data){
    $("#msg").html(data).find("#message2").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

**Edit:** This is what I mean by properly format:

```
function checkSession() {
    $.ajax({url: "session.php", success: function(data){
        if(data == 1) {
            var postFilen = 'msg.php';
            $.post(postFilen, function(data){
                $("#msg").html(data).find("#message2").fadeIn("slow");
            });
        } else {
            $('#message2').hide();
        }
    }});
}
```

Comment: Every time you open a new curly brace, you should indent the following code. That way it's obvious that the code is 'inside' the curly braces.

Comment: What editor are you using? Any decent text editor will help you match parens/braces and help you with your indentation as well.

Comment: Another thing to look out for is missing semicolons. Although you can sometimes leave them out, it's always best to use them (e.g. after `fadeIn("slow")`.